# Worklight adapters deployment failure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am new to worklight when I try to deploy I am getting the following error

```
Adapter deployment failed: No server host specified 
& No Mbean found
```

.

Comment: Your question is very general. Please take a look at How to ask first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have an address specified in Eclipse > Servers view > Worklight Development Server (double-click it) > Host name. Also attempt an Eclipse restart.